# Creating a new variable through another script in python

Tags: python, function, numpy

I've been wondering how to accomplish this.

I have 2 python scripts, the major one calls to the other and pass them 3 variables, then this script which is only one function returns a tuple of lenght 4. And finally I call this script through the first one.

My question is is there any method to make that the tuple creates a new variable, e.g a matrix or various vectors in the first script and so avoid to call the function over and over.

**Script 1**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

from Funcion_gamma import Fgamma

import time

start_time = time.time()

"Aluminio"

E=7e10       #Modulo de Young
v=0.33       #Modulo de Poison
G=2.63e10    #Modulo de cizalladura
h=0.00286    #Anchura de la placa
a=0.85       #Lado 1 de la placa
b=0.65       #Lado 2 de la placa
rho=2703.6   #Densidad del material
Kmuelle=3


"M y N"

m=7
n=m

Fgamma(Kmuelle,a,m)
```

**Script 2**

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

def Fgamma(KK,aa,M):

    'Definicion de las variables simbolicas'

    g, a, A, C, D, K, x = sp.symbols("g a A C D K x")

    'Funcion Gartner y sus derivadas' 

    X=(A*sp.cos(g*x/a))+(sp.sin(g*x/a))+(C*sp.exp(-g*x/a))+(D*sp.exp(-g*(a-x)/a))
    dx1=sp.diff(X,x,1)
    dx2=sp.diff(X,x,2)

    'Ecuaciones a resolver'

    eq1= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,0),0)
    eq2= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,0)/dx1.subs(x,0),K)
    eq3= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,a),0)
    eq4= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,a)/dx1.subs(x,a),-K)

    'Resolucion de las ecuaciones'

    D1=sp.solve(eq1,D)
    eq33 = eq3.subs(D, D1[0])
    C33=sp.solve(eq33,C)
    D11=D1[0].subs(C,C33[0])
    eq22=eq2.subs([(C, C33[0]),(D,D11)]) 
    A22=sp.solve(eq22,A)

    eq44=eq4.subs([(C,C33[0]),(D,D11)])
    A44=sp.solve(eq44,A)

    'Obtencion de A'

    AF=A22[0]-A44[0]
    AFF=sp.sympify(AF.subs([(K,KK),(a,aa)]))

    'Calculo de las raices de gamma'

    nn=np.linspace(0,M,num=M,endpoint=False,dtype='int')
    gamma=np.zeros(M)
    Afinal=np.zeros(M)
    Cfinal=np.zeros(M)
    Dfinal=np.zeros(M)    


    for jj in nn:
        gamma[jj]=sp.nsolve(sp.Eq(AFF,0),(3+(jj*np.pi)))
        Afinal[jj]=AFF.subs(g,gamma[jj])
        Cfinal[jj]=C33[0].subs([(A,Afinal[jj]),(a,aa),(g,gamma[jj])])
        Dfinal[jj]=D11.subs([(A,Afinal[jj]),(a,aa),(g,gamma[jj])])
    print gamma
    return gamma,Afinal,Cfinal,Dfinal
```

Comment: Do you want to cache the results of the function for faster access?

Comment: Yes, if possible create new variables on the first script and use that variables to store the results.

Comment: Then just do it. Use `cache = Fgamma(Kmuelle,a,m)` to store into the variable named `cache` the result of the function. Otherwise i might not be understanding correctly your question.

Comment: Yes, It worked as i wanted, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have file name for both script be script1.py and script2.py in same directory
To call the function named `Femma` in file   `script2.py` in `script1.py` you will use.
In file script1.py
    `import script2

    script2.Femma(args)`